# Is this a bad method to detect outliers

Tags: outliers

I thought of this way of detecting outliers. What are the "bad" properties of this method?

For example, say you have a time series, and you want to check if the latest observation is an outlier.

Firstly, I limit the time series to the past **N** elements, so that the time series are always of the same length, and data from way in the past is ignored.

Then I calculate the standard deviation with AND without the latest observation.

I then flag it as an outlier if that change is big, i.e. if $$(\text{std_with} - \text{std_without}) / \text{std_with}$$ is a big percentage.

Is this method bad? What are your criticisms?

Comment: Seems ok. Maybe add some sort of statistical test for significance of the difference? Otherwise you'd have to subjectively define "big change"

Comment: Right, defining a "big" change is the challenge here, as it will depend quite a bit on the N. If you have lots of observations, the addition/deletion of a single datapoint won't change the SD by much no matter how much of an outlier it is. Conversely, using smaller N will result in larger changes by chance alone.

Comment: This is a standard method (at least when the "big percentage" is chosen carefully)--but why make up your own method when you can read about them and find open source implementations?

Comment: Read about them where?

Comment: You need to be clear about what you mean by "outliers" and what your objectives are in identifying them. Here are a few places where you can read about them: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259654/what-is-the-basis-for-the-box-and-whisker-plot-definition-of-an-outlier/259663#259663 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15497/is-it-appropriate-to-identify-and-remove-outliers-because-they-cause-problems/15498#15498

Comment: Two good resources: [Barnett & Lewis](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Outliers+in+Statistical+Data%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471930945); [Madansky](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461283546).